# Whenever I install Linux Or Windows, A Boot Partition on Either Drive Can Get Deleted

Tags: windows, dual-boot, hardware

so I have a unique issue with my computer. My computer has an issue with either the CPU or the motherboard where dual-booting is basically my only option for having both Windows and Linux as I am a PC gamer and need Windows. The issue that initially occurs is that my PC will sometimes - after a shutdown - not boot or detect any drive. Which isn't much of an issue after a few restarts. But the thing is when I was doing this months ago I would have Manjaro and Windows on two separate drives. But if I restarted too much and this issue persists my computer would not detect either Windows or Manjaro. What will happen is that specifically the boot partition of either drive will be corrupted but the files would still be there for the OS in question.

My question is, is there any way to guarantee and fix it to the point where this cannot happen. Should I try a different Linux OS or replace my motherboard/CPU before attempting dual booting? Should I check the BIOS firmware and attempt to update it? Should I rely on no boot managers and try to boot using a grub console? What are your thoughts? I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

**Always** keep your firmware current.

Comment: Is there a chance that updating the BIOS can corrupt it to the point where my computer won't POST? Just being cautious.

Comment: There is always a chance. Just do not do it in the middle of a lightning storm or if laptop when battery is low. Almost all systems need UEFI updates, anyway, for mitigation of Meltdown and Spectre CPU vulnerabilities from cpu speculative execution and caching. Both Windows & Linux updated & continue to update kernels, but UEFI also needs updates. I have multiple drives with multiple installs. It seems if I change boot too much when experimenting with a new install, my system locks up. Usually cold boot works. Somethings I have to disconnect all drives, remove UEFI boot entries & start over.

Comment: @Mr.El -- if you were considering replacing the mobo or CPU, you have nothing to lose. 

Firmware upgrades are routine maintenance, but something most people neglect. I always try to keep all my machines' firmware current.

Just make sure you won't get a Windows update or virus alert or something in the middle of it and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you guys. Wish I had more advice for what to do with Linux tho. Because my computer won't boot to windows anymore because I reinstalled Linux again.

Comment: Is your PC new enough to have UEFI rather than a BIOS?

If so, is it in "SecureBoot mode"? This will often _stop_ Linux installing/booting, but if you turn it off for Linux, then sometimes a copy of Windows installed with it *on* will no longer boot.

The easiest answer to this, unfortunately, is to reinstall Windows with SecureBoot off.